# How to skip "please [Enter] to continue" during automating apt-get install?

Tags: automation

I have a script to install trough a automated process.

Here is an example:

```
  sudo apt-get update
    clear

    sudo apt-get install -y nginx
    clear
```

It works good, but not when I need to add a PPA.

Here I have this following message:

```
please [Enter] to continue or ...
```

At this point I need to press the enter to continue the process.

How can I skip this question and make it "Enter" by default?

This is an example that ask me to press [Enter]:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y sublime-text-installer
clear

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java  
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install -y oracle-java8-installer
clear
```

Comment: Can you show the __add PPA script__.

Comment: Hi George I added the PPA example.

Comment: please add the `-y` option to the script and see how it goes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `-y` option like `$ sudo add-apt-repository -y [repo]`.

before start asking questions, see the `man` pages for softwares.

## Update:

You can use `man add-apt-repository` for getting more information.

Comment: please show him how to use the `man pages`.